# Using a DbContext with postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Perhaps a simple question but I can't find the answer. I have a web form in which I declare my dbContext. However, when the page does postback, it overwrites the dbContext and I lose my object tracking. How do I keep the dbContext secure from changes until I'm ready to dispose of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggested pattern for using DbContext is to instantiate a new DbContext per HTTP request, and use that instance for the duration of that particular request.

You should not be attempting to keep an instance of DbContext across HTTP requests.

Comment: i am using viewstates. i dont know how to phrase my question correctly but should i not be keeping it across view states?

Comment: View states are a way to maintain some context between separate HTTP requests.  DbContext, however, should not be kept alive between HTTP requests.  Structure your code so that all changes that have to happen to the database happen in a single HTTP request.  If the postback sends something to the server that needs to be updated to the database, do it right then. Create a DbContext, use it, and dispose it.

Answer (score 4):

**Thou shalt not reuse `dbContext` between requests!**

Correct pattern to use is creating a new object per HTTP request (be it postback or not)

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    ...
}
```

**Why?**
Because `DbContext` it is a lightweight structure, but more importantly it is not thread safe.

If you want to update something on the postback use the same pattern, for example

```
object productId = //get it from request
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    //that's your old product
    var product = context.Select(p=>p.Id == product.Id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```